# How to find subgraphs of strongly connected components using networkx

Tags: python, networkx, connected-components

as `nx.strongly_connected_component_subgraphs()` is now removed in version 2.4, I have tried using `(G.subgraph(c) for c in strongly_connected_components(G))` similar to what we do for connected component subgraphs. but this just shows strongly_connected_component_subgraphs is deprecated. What to do for strongly connected subgraphs in networkx? sorry if this question is repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`nx.strongly_connected_components`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.strongly_connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.strongly_connected_components) as in your shared approach, should be fine:

```
(G.subgraph(c) for c in nx.strongly_connected_components(G))
```

This function is included in the [latest version, 2.5](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.strongly_connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.strongly_connected_components), and does not rely on any other deprecated methods, as you can see in the [source code](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/components/strongly_connected.html#strongly_connected_components). So make sure you aren't using the method that is actually raising the deprecation warning, `nx.strongly_connected_component_subgraphs`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've just checked, I'm getting the correct response using this even though there was the warning. As the function didn't print the graph object (i think it still returns the object) i thought it's an error. I haven't used the subgraphs method in the function, don't know why it still triggered that warning.